# After Fall Creators Update of Windows 10, can't make a GRUB entry for Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10

After Fall Creators Update, I can't get my Windows entry in GRUB to start Windows correctly.

I can jump into EFI and and start directly Windows Boot Manager, but I would love to be able to do it through GRUB.

I have two separate SSDs in my computer, one with Ubuntu and one with Windows (yes the fall creators update didn't destroy anything)

`os-prober` output is `/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi`

`blkid`

```
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="a94f5c98-0d83-42c8-9056-6526ccf7e7d2" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="CF20-9D16" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="198e6957-204f-44e4-a261-ab6e8798ffe3"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="81a01278-321b-42d5-9fd1-2877a0073e71" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a6d8a3e-797c-487d-9c72-82a986246940"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="9881b06e-0b9c-427d-8f72-96f9aca7b7ef" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="925ff9d7-a3e3-4b7c-86a5-102af4ea815f"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ExtraDrive1" UUID="6365d5d5-a2da-42c9-a709-d491a2b15392" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="629f6061-c802-4ee5-b645-a879bf5d8196"
/dev/sda2: UUID="3854B6F854B6B848" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="435c7330-c0cf-4088-ab2a-6e954d765105"
/dev/sda3: UUID="F4786E42786E03A8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="68855d34-731e-42d7-b99e-0e6293774ab2"
```

Finally the grub entry (through Grub Customizer, Type is `Other`):

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  CF20-9D16
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root CF20-9D16
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

What should I put in GRUB to make it boot windows again? Notice that fast boot is disabled on windows 10.

Comment: When `grub` disappears, I can boot with Ubuntu Live USB, install and run `boot-repair` to get it back.

Comment: But I didn't lose grub or anything. I have grub healthy, I can boot in ubuntu from grub, but if I click on the "Windows boot manager" entry in grub, it goes directly in blue screen (windows blue screen) saying windows couldn't boot. If I access windows partition manager from EFI though, I don't have any such problem

Comment: Boot repair might fix that too.